grub2: install in multiple ESP partitions
I'm installing a Linux server machine with two disks and an mdraid raid1 for most things, so the disks basically mirror each other. So, the system root partition is raid-based, as well as nearly everything else. There is one exception at the moment: Disk 1 contains the EFI partition, while disk 2 has just unused empty space there. On the other hand, everything would continue running if one disk breaks, but again with one exception: If disk 1 fails, I cannot boot anymore.
So, the obvious question here is: Is there a way to improve that? I'm using grub2 atm. Can I have an EFI partition on disk 2 as well and tell grub2 to install itself to both partitions?
I think that I could indeed create the EFI partition on disk 2, manually copy the stuff from disk 1's EFI partition to there, and manually register it with efibootmgr. I haven't tried it yet, but I guess this would work?! But this sounds annoying. It's not only additional code (I'm not doing the installation by hand, but in fact implement automation for that), but I'm also not sure what problems come with that. E.g. when do I need to repeat that (whenever grub-install is called, I guess) and how can I automate that?
So, if this is the best way, I will continue with just one EFI partition. But maybe there are already good solutions for this?
